# How to deploy 10 individual cars in Veins rather than changing the numbers in XML file

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am looking to deploy 10 cars in veins and how to connect each car. Is there any example in the veins tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Veins is able to spawn vehicles itself (and sync them to sumo). However, that is not covered in the examples yet. You should be able to find all the relevant code in the `TraCIScenarioManager` class.

Answer (score 0):

In Veins 5.0, you can instantiate a `TraCIVehicleInserter` module in your simulation to have Veins automatically insert `numVehicles` (see https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIVehicleInserter.ned#L43) vehicles in your simulation -- and to insert new ones whenever the number of active vehicles drops below the configured number.